# showing output from a called batch file on command prompt window?

Tags: windows, cmd, output, logfile

I have 2 batch files (say a.bat and b.bat). I am calling b.bat from a.bat: `@call b.bat`

There are some echo statements in b.bat, some DB start commands which usually show messages like **starting DB service...service started** .. some copy file statements...

I am putting all these messages form b.bat into a log file. for example: `sc delete ServName >> C:\test\log.log`.. These service delete messages are going into the log files successfully

When I run the b.bat directly, it shows me all these messages on the command prompt and the log file, however when i call b.bat from a.bat, these (copy file, start db etc etc) messages are not shown on the command prompt.. they only show up in the log file....

Is there a way to show all these return messages form b.bat file on the cmd window when its called by a.bat??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the result after execution, just add a "TYPE logfile.log" to the end.

Cmd doesn't support multiple output streams or replication, so if you want a "live view" one needs to process the line's one by one from the pipe:

> for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('Call b.bat') do @echo %f && @echo %f >>log.txt

If you are doing this from a.bat, you might need to replace %f to %%f